# Faster to randomize many results on MySQL Server or in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is it faster for the randomize the sort order of a large set of results on the MySQL server or after I have received the data in PHP?

Does anyone have any data to backup either side, or even anecdotal experience?

Comment: I would test to demonstrate whether a problem exists either way, before worrying about it. You'd have to have a huge, huge amount of data before it would matter much, I expect. In fact, it would be interesting to compare the amount of time you've taken posting this and digesting the answers, compared to choosing one approach, implementing it, switching, and comparing. (Just speculation, not a criticism; we all do these mental exercises.)

Comment: yes, but if someone answers this question well, then I will learn without all this investment of time, and i and others can improve their code. I think it's a good question to ask regardless of whether a problem currently exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My educated guess is that MySQL wins hands down. It's made to handle data this way. The sheer overhead of having to move all the data over to PHP for sorting gives it an advantange to boot.

You can find out for yourself by doing some benchmarking, of course.

Comment: I would agree that this is the likely answer, however I can't do the benchmark right now, I don't think I have enough data at the moment, but I do see it as a problem in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

For sure you should do it on `MySQL` side.

But note that `ORDER BY RAND()` is *very* inefficient in `MySQL` since it requires `filesort`.

See how to select `10` random rows efficiently with a single table scan:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                @lim := 10
        FROM    t_random
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        (
        SELECT  r.*,
                @lim := @lim - 1
        FROM    t_random r
        WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                AND RAND() < @lim / @cnt
        ) i
```

See this article in my blog for performance details:

- [**Selecting random rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)

For a `1,000,000` records table, it runs in less than a second instead of `15` seconds using `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using RAND() in MySQL will **definitely** be faster.

To randomise via PHP you would have to query the db and push the data into memory, so you have a whole extra step adding overhead to your sort process.

In MySQL, this type of query will not be as fast as ordering by an indexed value, but it will still be highly optimised.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you use rand() as the object of the order by statement:

```
  select * from foo_table order by rand() limit 100
```