# randomize mysql output as easily as possible

Tags: php, mysql

I have the mysql statement:

```
$mysql=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM table1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");
```

From this I'm doing

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){
    echo $row['name'].'<br>';
}
```

Now i'm trying to shuffle the rows I got out of mysql without using ORDER BY RAND() as thats causing slowdown.

Whats the correct syntax to program this in so the rows come out shuffled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need them to

> "come out shuffled"

...as in "out of the database," then you can do the shuffle immediately after you retrieve all of the records.

Since you can [fetch all rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) as an associative array, you can then just [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the result.  This will give you a random order of the rows returned.

In your case:

```
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM table1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");

$results = array(); //this might be unnecessary

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql))
{
    array_push($results, $row);
}

shuffle($results);
foreach( $results as $row )
{
    echo $row['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Tested, confirmed working.  Still slow, but faster than ORDER BY rand().  Thanks rockerrest

Comment: @David you could probably get exponential speed increases by switching your query to the [PDO fetchall function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and then doing the `shuffle` on what that returns.  The slowest thing with this whole code, no matter what way you do it, is doing a database request for EVERY row.  That's a little silly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle):

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){
    $results[] = $row['name'];
}

shuffle($results);
```

Comment: Dammit, you beat me by 40 seconds ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the results into a php array then pick them out of the array at random.

This should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){
    $array[] = $row['name'];
}

$c = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
    $r = rand(0, $c - ($i + 1));
    echo $array[$r];
    unset($array[$r]);
}
```

Comment: This, although more difficult to understand would be more efficient I think due to my arrays being full of lots of text.  I'll give this method some more thought later.  Thanks

Comment: It might actually be slower than the other methods, I wasn't aware of shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

Using `shuffle()` in PHP or any PHP-side sorting method, will only randomize, at each execution, the very same 10 rows (`LIMIT 10`) from the MySQL table.

Although more efficient, the results will be completely different to what is achieved by `ORDER BY RAND()`.

It's difficult to know which of the two behaviors the OP asks for, but if it's the second one (since he has tried `ORDER BY RAND()`), I propose to use a more efficient way for retrieving 10 rows at random *from the whole MySQL table* (not a subset of its rows): see **[Quassnoi's solution](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)** (and SO question [Faster to randomize many results on MySQL Server or in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851032/faster-to-randomize-many-results-on-mysql-server-or-in-php)).